# How can I loop through an API call without it repeating the first value?

Tags: python

So, I want to loop through a list of top games on twitch and I am having a bit of trouble.

I took out the stuff I need from the API call, such as name, viewers and thumbnail but whenever I try to loop through the other 20 games, it just repeats the same game on top of the API call.

```
from twitch import TwitchClient
import pprint


client = TwitchClient('<CLIENT_ID>')
games = client.games.get_top(limit=20)

for game in games:
    game_info = {
        'game_name': games[0]['game']['name'],
        'game_viewers': games[0]['viewers'],
        'game_thumbnail': games[0]['game']['logo']['large']
    }
    pprint.pprint(game_info)
```

Comment: Well, `games[0]` stays the same, no matter how often you iterate. You do not even use the loop variable `game` anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're looping through `games` and not using your intended `game` variable in the loop whatsoever. You're only accessing the first game by using `games[0]` every iteration. Just change this one thing and this should fix your code

```
for game in games:
    game_info = {
        'game_name': game['game']['name'],
        'game_viewers': game['viewers'],
        'game_thumbnail': game['game']['logo']['large']
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You specifically told it to *ignore* the individual `game` values and revert to the first item in the list with

```
for game in games:
    game_info = {
        'game_name': games[0]['game']['name'],
```

You have to use your loop variable!

```
for game in games:
    game_info = {
        'game_name': game['game']['name'],
```